# My customarayadapter appears to be passing wrong var

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am having a customArrayAdapter to show my pictures in my gridview. Everything goes well when I open the activity, but when I scroll down and back up, it shows the triangleRed for some items while the pictureCorrect is 1 for that id (I checked my database in DDMS to be sure). It appears to be happening with the same items all the time... this is a piece of my custom adapter:

```
if (mView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.caa_xml, null);
        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.iv_caarow);
        ImageView triangle = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.iv_triangle);
        image.setAlpha(255);
        triangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //… some additional code to define resizedBitmap

        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        image.setImageDrawable(bmd);

        if (mView != null) {

            Picture pictureGiven = null;
            loadDataBase();
            pictureGiven = myDbHelper.getPictureGiven(getItem(position).getId(),
                    player);

            int attempts = pictureGiven.getAttempts();
            int correctPicture = pictureGiven.getPictureCorrect(); //returns 0 or 1

            triangle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (correctPicture == 1) {
                triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } 
            if (correctPicture != 1 && attempts > 0) {
                triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                triangle.setImageResource(R.drawable.trianglered);

            }

        }
        return mView;
    }
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: I have experienced the same thing, but haven't found a good soultion for it. It feels like a small bug in the listview regarding the lag introduced by working on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to view recycling, you need to set the content of your triangle in every possible case.

Here, if correctPicture == 1, your triangle image resource is whatever is was previously, possibly trianglered.

```
        if (correctPicture == 1) {
            triangle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                   // Add whatever initial value it is
            triangle.setImageResource(R.drawable.initvalue);
        }
```

Comment: Ah I see, it sounds logic. This does the trick, woaha :D Thanks, was searching for it for a while!